# Network IP from Docker not working for React + Vite.js therefore can't access k8s pod

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes

I have a very simple react typescript application and using Vite for the first time to replace Webpack.

I have the following vite.config.js:

```
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
    open: false,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
  },
```

and created a Dockerfile with these instructions:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
COPY ./build-prod ./build-prod
COPY ./node_modules ./node_modules
RUN npm install husky -g --production
RUN npm install esbuild-linux-arm64 --production
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

When I now run `docker run -p 3000:3000 hello-world-app-frontend` I can access my app with `http://localhost:3000/` but opening the network address `http://172.17.0.3:3000/` just loads an untitled window.

I think this is especially a problem for me as I want to create a basic Kubernetes config like this:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: hello-world-app-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-world-app-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-world-app-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: hello-world-app-frontend
          image: hello-world-app-frontend
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
      restartPolicy: Always

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: hello-world-app-frontend
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31000
  selector:
    app: hello-world-app-frontend
```

But opening the IP address from my Pod returns nothing in my Chrome (f.e. http://10.106.213.128:3000/).

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
default                pod/hello-world-app-frontend-77899b46d7-cc4td    1/1     Running   0             16h
default                pod/hello-world-app-frontend-77899b46d7-vqtbz    1/1     Running   0             16h

NAMESPACE              NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default                service/hello-world-app-frontend    NodePort    10.106.213.128   <none>        3000:31000/TCP           16h
```

Can somebody give me a few hints how I can access the React application from my k8s pod?

Comment: `10.106.213.128` is a ClusterIP and will only be accessible inside the cluster. If you want to reach the app from your browser, you can use the NodePort, which is already part of your example. Try `http://NODE_IP:31000`